# Return a list from a function in Python

Tags: python, list, function

I'm new to python so pardon me if this is a silly question but I'm trying to return a list from a function. This is what I have so far but I'm getting nowhere. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm trying to make a simple function that called `make_a_list(1, 5, "Christian")` that returns a list that looks like this: `[1, 5, "Christian]`

```
def make_a_list():
    my_list = ["1", "5", "Christian"]
    for item in my_list:
    return my_list

my_list = make_a_list()

print(my_list)
```

Comment: You don't need to write "for item in my_list:", You've already made the list in the line before it, so just return it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
def make_a_list(*args):
    return list(args)

print(make_a_list(1, 5, "Christian"))  # [1, 5, "Christian"]
```

But you do not have to since there is a Python built-in that already does that:

```
print(list((1, 5, "Christian")))  # [1, 5, "Christian"]
```

Notice that with the second option you are passing the whole `tuple` and not the elements separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, the question is unclear

```
def make_a_list(*args):
    def inner():
        return list(args)
    return inner
```

you would then use it like this

```
make_list_1 = make_a_list(1, 5, "Christian") # make_list_1 is a function
make_list_2 = make_a_list(2, 10 "A different list") # make_list_2 is a different function

list_1 = make_list_1() # list_1 is a list
print(list_1) # that we can print
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you do not need to make a dedicated function to create a list. You can create lists very easily. For example:

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
print(list1)

>>['one','two', 'three']
```

Check out the following website for more information not only about lists, but other python concepts.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm